# Call kd (console windbg) options programmatically

Tags: c#, windbg

I need to extract stack trace from dump file. I use such code for calling kd

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\
kd -y srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols -z C:\dmp.dmp
```

after that in cmd manually I type:

```
.ecxr
```

and then

```
k
```

Question is: how to call .ecxt, k and other same staff programmatically, like that:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\kd.exe",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = @"-y srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols -z C:\dmp.dmp"
};

var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

string stdOut = string.Empty;

proc.OutputDataReceived += (whosend, args) => stdOut += args.Data;

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show(stdOut);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinDbg and KD take a command line argument `-c` where you can pass commands. Don't forget to include a `;q` at the end so that the debugger terminates when completed.

When your script becomes longer, you might want to put it into a file and run it as a [script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566261(v=vs.85).aspx) with one of the `$<` commands.